# Stuck with some functions in python

Tags: python-3.x

i was just trying to figure out coding in python. and stuck into a program.
the functions are working seperatly but aren't running in the program. STUCK! don't know what to do.
i/m very new to coding and please provide me with some ways to practice and improve my coding.

```
#Cows and Bulls game!
import random
#to make a 4-Digit number.
#TASKS:
#1. Generat a random 4-digit nmber.
#2. Ask the user to enter the 4-Digit numer.
#3. Compare te numbers obtained from the user and generated number.
#4. if correct digit at correct place give a cow.
#5. if correct digit at wrong place give a bull.

def MakeNumber():
    num = []
    attempt = 0
    for i in range (4):
        a = random.randrange(0,9)
        num.append(a)

    if len(num)>len(set(num)):
        MakeNumber()    
    return(num) 
    print(num)



def user():
    user = (input("Enter a 4-Digit Number- "))
    lst = []
    for i in range(0,len(user)):
        lst.append(user[i])
    return(lst) 
    

        

def compare(num,user):
    cows = 0 
    bulls = 0
    for i in range(4):
        if num[i] == user[i]:
            cows += 1
        if num[i] in user:
            bulls += 1  
    print(cows,bulls)   

if __name__ == '__main__':              
    num1=MakeNumber()
    lst1=user()
    compare(num1,lst1)
```

Comment: What makes you think the functions "aren't running in the program"?

Comment: when running the program.it just showing me the output of the user() function and nothing else after i enter the 4-digit number

Comment: `user` doesn't have any output.  And if it is calling `user`, then it is "running" at least 2 of your 3 functions.  Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: i tried debugging and got the following error in the **user** : **Exception: input() lost sys.stdin    and i don't know what it is

Comment: @AmitBaghel check out my answer, and let me know if that works out for you in any way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing right, just some modifications are required.

1. Your logic for `cow` and `bull` is correct. It is just that, if a number is like `1234`, and the random number is `5402`, so the outcome is `cow=0` and `bull=2`, since 4 is there two times as per the check `if num[i] in user`. So, if you are good for that, we are good to go
2. You don't have to make an `array`, `string` for `num` will do the job
3. Accept the `input` only if it is 4 digits
4. do not make the variable name same as method name. Like `user` and `user()`

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
import random

def MakeNumber():
    num = ""
    for i in range (4):
       # In python you can do concatenation in string easily
       # which saves your list definition in the code
       num += str(random.randrange(0,9))
    return num


def user():
    userInput = input("Enter a 4-Digit Number: ")
    # this is a recusrion, and accepts the input only, if the input is length 4
    # study about how recursion works, it works as Stack, so read upon it
    if len(userInput) == 4: 
        return userInput
    else:
        print('Please check your length, it is not 4. Try again...')
        return user() 

def compare(num,user):
    cows = 0 
    bulls = 0
    # for check, what is the random number and what is the user input
    print(num + ", " + user)
    
    # your logic only
    for i in range(4):
        if num[i] == user[i]:
            cows += 1
        if num[i] in user:
            bulls += 1 
        
    print(cows,bulls)   

if __name__ == '__main__':              
    num1 = MakeNumber()
    list1 = user()
    compare(num1,list1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> Enter a 4-Digit Number: 12345
>>> Please check your length, it is not 4. Try again...
>>> Enter a 4-Digit Number: 123456
>>> Please check your length, it is not 4. Try again...
>>> Enter a 4-Digit Number: 1234
>>> 2447, 1234
>>> 0 3
```

Comment: Yes @Alok now i understood! thanks for your help. Can you suggest some good documentation for python?

Comment: Happy to help @AmitBaghel. You can refer to the [Python Official Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) for this. Also, if you really want to dive deep into `Python`, then start doing `Competitive Programming` from `LeetCode/HackerRank/Codechef`, with this you will learn about different DS,Algos in Python. **Make some projects in Python, so that you can do implementation of your knowledge/work**. Even I am not a very brilliant guy in python, although, I keep exploring Python's new information

Comment: Thanks! This will surely help me. I'm trying to dive deep and this will be really helpful.